# Show Elements Verticaly by CSS

Tags: html, css, formatting

i have a list like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

and i want to show them like this picture
[image]

*that way In the beginning Fill in the first column and then second and etc.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [column-count](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/columns):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  column-count: 2;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

> My colomns number is dynamic and may change. But there are 3 items in one column(max).

Use [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex):

```css
ul {
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 60px; /* 60 / 3 = 20 */
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column wrap;
}

ul > li {
  height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
```

However, you'll have to add some fixed `height`.

Comment: my colomns number is dynamic and may change.but there are 3 items in one column(max)

Comment: tnx. now i want have a free space after seceond colomn(for place image).thats mean i want all columns to fit 50% of <ul> .for example if i have two columns The width of each column be 25%.plz help me

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, you can make this dynamic.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var items = $("ul li").length;
  $("ul").css("column-count", Math.ceil(items / 3));
});
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

If you want this in pure JS

```js
var list = document.querySelector("ul");
var items = document.querySelectorAll("ul li").length;
list.setAttribute("style", "column-count :" + Math.ceil(items / 3));
```

```css
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>One</li>
  <li>Two</li>
  <li>Three</li>
  <li>Four</li>
  <li>Five</li>
  <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss3_columns

```css
ul {columns: 2;
  -webkit-columns: 2;
  -moz-columns: 2;}
ul li {list-style:none;}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li>Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
</ul>
```